# Google sheets query with sum returning unwanted text

Tags: google-sheets, sum

Im not sure where I am making a mistake here. In the following sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h0XR399z6OHqzyX509WwnLBiqHX4nq4FmofaJd-HoAw/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet 1 has the raw data. I am trying to sum the same in sheet based on different criteria but I am getting an issue with a simple query. In sheet order_payment_heads a simple sum query in C2 returns the su but also the text sum amount. 
Feels like I am doing something really basic wrong here but any help would be great. query being used is given below

'''=QUERY(Sheet1!A:X,"select SUM(O) where H = '"&A2&"'",1)'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a brand new tab, try this in cell A1

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:X,"select H,V,SUM(O) where H is not null group by H,V label SUM(O)'Price Head'")
```

Hopefully that will get what you're after in one go.  "group by" is really the only reason that query distinguishes itself from other functions.

Comment: Hi the query in question gives the answer for the first column of sum but i need additional columns for sum where there is an additional condition on column M. So for example I got the first column using the query format given by you  QUERY(Sheet1!A:X,"select H,V,SUM(O) where H is not null and M = 'ItemPrice' group by H,V label SUM(O)'Price Head'"). But the next column I need has to correspond to the same entries but with a different condition on M. How would I do that if I cant match on order-id and sku columns

Comment: you probably just need to pivot by M.  Try this instead:

=QUERY(Sheet1!A:X,"select H,V,SUM(O) where H is not null group by H,V pivot M")

Comment: hi that seems to do the trick for what i need right now but the original query I had was still which the sum query matching a condition was returning the answer with an additional sum amount text as I did not see the same in the tutorials I saw

Comment: I see.  I think the issue is that query() isn't meant to be used that way.  what you'd want in that scenario where you plan on dragging it down for each unique settlement/sku would be a SUMIFS().  somethign like....

=SUMIFS(Sheet1!O:O,Sheet1!H:H,A2,Sheet1!V:V,B2,Sheet!M:M,"Item Price")